# Navigation to jQuery Mobile dialog not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm simply trying to dynamically create a form with input boxes and a submit button. The number of boxes created is the amount selected in the select menu. The problem is every time I click on the dynamically created button in my form Called Go to Step 3 I don't navigate to my dialog and I have no clue why not. Any help would really be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<div id ="steptwo" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role ="header">
            <h1> </h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role = "content">
            <center>
                    <p>This is step two of four. We require at this stage information about the cars you drive for our new system. Please select the number of cars you own in the list below:</p>

                        <select id="carcount">
                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2">2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                          <option value="4">4</option>
                          <option value="5">5</option>
                          <option value="6">6</option>
                          <option value="7">7</option>
                          <option value="8">8</option>
                          <option value="9">9</option>
                          <option value="10">10</option>
                        </select>

                    <div id="NumberOfCars">
                    </div>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div> 

<div id ="diaglogchildren" data-role="dialog" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header">
             <h3>Do you have any children?</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role = "content">
            <center>
                <input type="submit" id ="ChildrenYes" name="ChildrenYes" value="Yes" data-theme="a">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" id ="ChildrenNo" name="ChildrenNo" value="No" data-theme="a">
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#steptwo",
    function()
    { 
        $("#carcount").change(function()
        {
            $("#NumberOfCars").empty();
            var stringbuild = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < $("#carcount").val(); i++) 
            {
                stringbuild = stringbuild +  '<input type="text" id="car' + i + '" name="carmake" placeholder="Please enter Vehicle ' + (i+1) + ' Make"><input type="text" id="car' + i + '" name="carreg" placeholder="Please enter Vehicle ' + (i+1) + ' Registration Number">';
            };

            stringbuild = '<form name="CarOnwerDetails" action="#" method="post">' + stringbuild + '<input type="submit" id="CarSubmit" name="CarSubmit" value="Go to Step 3" data-theme="a"></form>';

            alert(stringbuild);
            $("#NumberOfCars").append(stringbuild).trigger("create");
        });

        $("#CarSubmit").click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = "#diaglogchildren";
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Just change this:

```
$("#CarSubmit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "#diaglogchildren";
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).on("click","#CarSubmit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "#diaglogchildren";
});
```

### Working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id ="steptwo" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role ="header">
                <h1> </h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role = "content">
                <center>
                    <p>This is step two of four. We require at this stage information about the cars you drive for our new system. Please select the number of cars you own in the list below:</p>

                    <select id="carcount">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                    </select>

                    <div id="NumberOfCars">
                    </div>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div id ="diaglogchildren" data-role="dialog" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>Do you have any children?</h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role = "content">
                <center>
                    <input type="submit" id ="ChildrenYes" name="ChildrenYes" value="Yes" data-theme="a"/>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" id ="ChildrenNo" name="ChildrenNo" value="No" data-theme="a"/>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).on("pageinit","#steptwo", function(){ 

            $("#carcount").change(function(){
                $("#NumberOfCars").empty();
                var stringbuild = '';

                for (var i = 0; i < $("#carcount").val(); i++) 
                {
                    stringbuild = stringbuild +  '<input type="text" id="car' + i + '" name="carmake" placeholder="Please enter Vehicle ' + (i+1) + ' Make"><input type="text" id="car' + i + '" name="carreg" placeholder="Please enter Vehicle ' + (i+1) + ' Registration Number">';
                };

                stringbuild = '<form name="CarOnwerDetails" action="#" method="post">' + stringbuild + '<input type="submit" id="CarSubmit" name="CarSubmit" value="Go to Step 3" data-theme="a"></form>';

                alert(stringbuild);
                $("#NumberOfCars").append(stringbuild).trigger("create");
            });


            /*$("#CarSubmit").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.location.href = "#diaglogchildren";
            });*/
            $(document).on("click","#CarSubmit", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                window.location.href = "#diaglogchildren";
            });    
        }); 
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any particular reason why my way wasn't working?

Comment: Yes, jQuery Mobile don't like classic click bindings. If possible (and it should be in 99,9 % of cases) use delayed event binding just like in my case. This is rather long topic and I will not describe it in more details here, but in few days I will write a blog article about this topic and I will post it here for you to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try using $.mobile.changePage('#dialogchildren');